# How does a front-end application user gets identified in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How should I allow external application users(that do not run nodes on the network) to allow using an hyperledger fabric app ? How are the identified in the network ?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a REST API as the gateway to the blockchain network. Depending on how much you want to lock down functionality, you could refine the REST URLs to divert to different users in the wallet so that perhaps some might have read only access and others might have higher levels. You can set up the contract code to recognise which user is currently trying to perform an action and take steps to restrict them more. It all depends on your requirements. The external users could be given access to URLs specific to their organisations which would seek to access blockchain through a wallet dedicated to such an organisation. Therefore, there is no possibiity of crossover with other orgnisations.

If you are developing using Node.js, it is very easy and quick to set up an example REST API using Express.